# No voice transmission, PJSIP behind NAT

Tags: audio, voip, pjsip, nat, pjsua2

I'm trying write softphone app with pjsua. Everything works well, sound is transmitted bidirectional, when I use Asterisk and softphones in the same local network - 192.168.10.XXX, but when I hide my softphone behind NAT, I can't hear any incoming sound, outcoming sound works OK.

Endpoint with my app has ip: 192.168.12.233, routers public address is 192.168.10.216, and Asterisk - 192.168.10.15. Port translation on router is configured to forward 5060 port for SIP and 4000-5000 for RTP. I tried to set ip public addres in pjsua configuration but with no effect.

Here is INVITE SIP message from my app, I think the problem is witch the SDP 'c' field which contains wrong ip addres. Do you know how to change it in pjsua or how to fix that sound problem? Maybe I should change something in Asterisk config?

```
INVITE sip:112@192.168.10.15 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.10.216:40173;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj1cb51c72-d924-4f3e-9075-6fa17e39b3be
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:500@192.168.10.15;tag=c80893bb-4b11-4def-b0e9-59bb82b88630
To: sip:112@192.168.10.15
Contact: <sip:500@192.168.10.216:40173;ob>
Call-ID: cc07dcae-1f51-4fd9-b3b0-508da40b2752
CSeq: 11230 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800
Min-SE: 90
User-Agent: GMIDFOO00
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   350

v=0
o=- 3787399917 3787399917 IN IP4 192.168.12.233
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0 Unknown
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 9 8 96
c=IN IP4 192.168.12.233
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 192.168.12.233
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:96 0-16
a=ssrc:938347045 cname:56c230b34489dbbe
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Asterisk PJSIP it can happen due to two things.

#### Codec Support

One is codecs support, make sure you have specified codecs to be used and both sides can communicate on at least on available codec. you can check this issue by running following command, I don't see any error but you can try following command to check RTP communication

```
rtp set debug on
```

Now you will big list of information, check both side being communicating or only one side is moving packets. If there is issue than it is due to firewall. make sure you have allowed following ports in your firewall

```
 TCP/UDP 5060 and UDP 10000-25000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending private IP in SDP pay load to resolve this you need to use either STUN or ICE server please enable ICE or stun server on pjsip App side

**192.168.12.233** public IP usually done by ICE or STUN server.it must be publicly accessible IP address

Answer (score 0):

Setting `allow_sdp_nat_rewrite` of `pjsua_acc_config` structure should be enough here ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__acc__config.htm#a2195ff0bc806dc1e812905af632285d2)).